# How to permanently stop timer and clear old data from timer?

Tags: java, gwt, timer

I am using the following loop for working with time :

```
Timer innerTimer = new Timer() {         
      @Override
      public void run() {
        for(final Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
          if(stopTimer) {
            this.cancel();
            break;
          }

          xmassContext = xmassCanvas.getContext2d();
          xmassContext.beginPath();  
          xmassContext.clearRect(rectangle.getXMin(), rectangle.getYMin(), rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
          xmassContext.setFillStyle(controlColor.get(rectangles.indexOf(rectangle)));
          xmassContext.setGlobalAlpha(brightness.get(rectangles.indexOf(rectangle))/100);
          xmassContext.rect(rectangle.getXMin(), rectangle.getYMin(), rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());           
          xmassContext.fill();
        }
      }
    };

    innerTimer.schedule(tmptimerDuration);
    tmptimerDuration = tmptimerDuration + frameDurationTime; 

    if(stopTimer) innerTimer.cancel();
```

In the above code `stopTimer` is a global static variable. When I want to stop timer then I set `stopTimer = true;` and for next execution I set `stopTimer = false;`

After setting the `timer = true` timer will stop. But for next execution it will store the old data so for the next time timer will start with the old data. How can I remove the queue (old) data from timer in GWT?

Comment: use instance variable if you want a fresh copy every time.

Comment: Whats the initial value of the global static variable stopTimer?

Comment: @KrishnaChandran Global value of  stopTimer initial is false;

Comment: You want to reset that innerTimer object right?

Comment: Yes. When I restart timer, Timer will start the data process with old data.

Comment: I dont know whether it will work or not try referencing the innerTimer obj to null. if (stopTimer) { innerTimer.cancel(); innerTimer= null ; }

Comment: @KrishnaChandran After setting innerTimer = null timer continue to executing and throws null pointer exception.

Comment: could you post in all the code.